# Why does in Swift3 boolean value from NSUserDefaults is visible as 0 instead of "false"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

In my Swift app I'm saving boolean values to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
defaults.set(false, forKey: "mySwitch")
defaults.set(true, forKey: "mySecondSwitch")
```

later on, when I'm constructing query to alamofire:

```
var params = [
        "switch1": defaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitch") as AnyObject
    ] as [String: AnyObject]
```

and printing params with `print(params)` I'm seeing `switch1 = 0`. How can I make it so it's transferred to server as `switch1 = false`?

I cannot change the structure of the array, it has to stay as `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: Because `Bool` isn't an `AnyObject`. What you're seeing is an `NSNumber` wrapping the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you convert a `Bool` to `AnyObject`, `true` becomes 1 and `false` becomes 0. That behaviour cannot be changed I don't think.

```
// prints 1
print(true as AnyObject)
```

The only workaround that I can think of is:

```
var params = [
    "switch1": defaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitch").description as AnyObject
    ] as [String: AnyObject]
print(params)
```

As you can see, I accessed `description` before `as AnyObject`. The output is shown below:

```
["switch1": false]
```

Apparently, "switch1" gets those quote marks but not `false`.

Note that I know nothing about Alamofire so I don't know whether sending `["switch1": false]` as a parameter to a server will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 don't use `AnyObject` instead use `Any`.

So change the code like below,

```
var params = [
        "switch1": defaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitch") as Bool
    ] as [String: Bool]
```

Or if contains multiple types of params then like below,

```
var params = [
        "switch1": defaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitch") as Bool
    ] as [String: Any]
```

Answer (score -3):

in general BOOL is always be A int which Contain `0 or 1`that mean

if the statement is true it will return 1 like

```
    if(_bool){

    //its mean if _bool ==1 then execute this 
    }else{

//its mean if _bool ==0 then execute this 
}
```

that is the one of the reason NSArray dose not contain int value but NSMutableArray can contain int value